# Шрифты в IE и FF

Tags: html, css

Вобщем редактировал шаблон и наткнулся на одну проблему. Сделал див вида:

```
<div style="font-size: 2px;">розетка</div>
```

В Опере он отображается замечательно, но при проссмотре сайта через FF или IE этот шрифт становится невероятно мелким. Мелким до такой степени, что чтобы его разглядеть, приходится приближать шаблон сайта на максимум. Вот как он отображается в IE и FF без приближения или отдаления:

[image: фотка]

Да, да. Вот эта мелкая черточка под 150р - это и есть шрифт в IE и FF. Помогите решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У оперы у вас отключены стили сайтов, вот почему вы видите нормально. Вы сами-то головой подумайте, что такое шрифт в 2 пикселя?? Две точки в высоту должны поместить в себе букву. Представили?? Теперь может поймете, что это нормально, что вы не видите нормально такой шрифт (у вас же px- пиксели а не pt- пункты).

Comment: А как включить стили сайтов для оперы?

Comment: в настройках посмотреть параметр - использовать свои таблицы стилей. (или что то подобное) или настройки - панели инструментов - панель просмотра (поставить галочку) и в ней там где режим автора или пользователя есть настройка всего этого. что использовать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Разобрался!